# I am trying to make this code work but failing due to End With

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting the

> End With without With

error and I cannot find the issue.

I have attempted to add `else` below the 1st set of `.visible=true` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub Owners()

    Sheets("Start").Activate
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next ws

    With Worksheets("Start")
        Dim stateMatch As Variant
        stateMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B2").Value, Sheets("List").Range("K2:K32"), 0)

        Dim numOwnerMatch As Variant
        numOwnerMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B3").Value, Sheets("List").Range("D2:D3"), 0)

        If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) Then
            If numOwnerMatch = 1 Then
                Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
            End If
            If numOwnerMatch = 2 Then
                Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("2nd OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
                Worksheets("2nd OwnerPPW").Visible = True
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It looks as though you were missing an end if near the bottom. Spacing your groupings might help you with this going forward as it is much easier to see when an IF/WITH/etc opens and closes.

```
Sub Owners()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stateMatch As Variant
    Dim numOwnerMatch As Variant

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name Then
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next ws

    With Worksheets("Start")
        stateMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B2").Value, Sheets("List").Range("K2:K32"), 0)
        numOwnerMatch = Application.Match(.Range("B3").Value, Sheets("List").Range("D2:D3"), 0)
        If IsNumeric(stateMatch) And IsNumeric(numOwnerMatch) Then
            If numOwnerMatch = 1 Then
                Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
            End If
            If numOwnerMatch = 2 Then
                Worksheets("1st OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("2nd OwnerStatement").Visible = True
                Worksheets("1st OwnerPPW").Visible = True
                Worksheets("2nd OwnerPPW").Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```